# Correlation between pre-pregnancy training level of abdominal muscles and the risk of getting diastasis recti

Tags: exercise, obstetrics, physiology, abdominal

Is there any evidence that (very) strong or (very) weak abdominal muscles before becoming pregnant increases or decreases the risk of developing diastasis recti during pregnancy?

If so, what are the physiological reasons for this? Do you have any references about studies about this subject?